# Sierpinski triangle: program not functioning properly

Tags: c

I have a code for generating  the Sierpinski triangle that isn't working the way i want it to. It seems that the computer only reads the coordinates for the third subtriangle (top) and the bottom left subtriangle and completely ignores the second one(bottom right)! The result being that I only have half the initial triangle. Why does this happen if their indexes are different (one is m and the other p)? How can I change it so that it reads all three subtriangles? My code is written in C in Code:Blocks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NTRIANGULOS (1<<3)

struct Triangulo
{
    float xA,yA;
    float xB,yB;
    float xC,yC;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct Triangulo triangulo[NTRIANGULOS];
    int n,m,p,ntriangulos;

    FILE*fout;
    fout=fopen("tri.txt","w");

    triangulo[0].xA = 0;
    triangulo[0].yA = 0;
    triangulo[0].xB = 1;
    triangulo[0].yB = 0;
    triangulo[0].xC = 0.5;
    triangulo[0].yC = 1;
    ntriangulos=1;

    do{

        for(n=ntriangulos-1; n>=0&&ntriangulos<NTRIANGULOS; n--){
            m=ntriangulos;

            /* segundo triangulo */
            triangulo[m].xA=triangulo[n].xA + (triangulo[n].xB - triangulo[n].xA)/2 ;
            triangulo[m].yA=triangulo[n].yA;

            triangulo[m].xB=triangulo[n].xB;
            triangulo[m].yB=triangulo[n].yB;

            triangulo[m].xC=triangulo[n].xA + 3*(triangulo[n].xB - triangulo[n].xA)/4;
            triangulo[m].yC=triangulo[n].yA + (triangulo[n].yC- triangulo[n].yA)/2 ;


            p=ntriangulos;
            /* tercer triangulo */
            triangulo[p].xA=triangulo[n].xA + (triangulo[n].xB - triangulo[n].xA)/4;
            triangulo[p].yA=triangulo[n].yA + (triangulo[n].yC - triangulo[n].yA)/2;

            triangulo[p].xB=triangulo[n].xA + 3*(triangulo[n].xB -triangulo[n].xA)/4;
            triangulo[p].yB=triangulo[n].yA + (triangulo[n].yC -triangulo[n].yB)/2;

            triangulo[p].xC= triangulo[n].xC;
            triangulo[p].yC= triangulo[n].yC;


            /* primer triangulo - inicial */

            triangulo[n].xC=triangulo[n].xA + (triangulo[n].xB - triangulo[n].xA)/4;
            triangulo[n].yC=triangulo[n].xA +(triangulo[n].yC - triangulo[n].yA)/2;

            triangulo[n].xB=triangulo[n].xA + (triangulo[n].xB - triangulo[n].xA)/2;
            triangulo[n].yB=triangulo[n].yB;

            triangulo[n].xA=triangulo[n].xA;
            triangulo[n].yA=triangulo[n].yA;

            ntriangulos++;
        }

    } while(ntriangulos<NTRIANGULOS);

    for(n=0;n<ntriangulos;n++)
    {
        fprintf(fout,"%g\t%g\n%g\t%g\n%g\t%g\n", triangulo[n].xA,  triangulo[n].yA, 
                triangulo[n].xB, triangulo[n].yB, triangulo[n].xC, triangulo[n].yC);
    }

    fclose(fout);
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
p=ntriangulos;
```

should be

```
p=ntriangulos+1;
```

Also, the way you have written the for loop, it will stop after first loop.

In the first iteration,

```
n = 0
```

In the second iteration,

```
n = -1
```

the expression `n>=0&&ntriangulos<NTRIANGULOS` evaluates to false when `n = -1`

**Update**

Here's a revised version of your program. I have tried to explain some of the core logic in comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NTRIANGULOS 81
// (1<<3)


struct Triangulo
{
   float xA,yA;
   float xB,yB;
   float xC,yC;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   struct Triangulo triangulo[NTRIANGULOS];
   int n,m,p,ntriangulos;

   FILE*fout;
   fout=fopen("tri.txt","w");

   triangulo[0].xA = 0;
   triangulo[0].yA = 0;
   triangulo[0].xB = 1;
   triangulo[0].yB = 0;
   triangulo[0].xC = 0.5;
   triangulo[0].yC = 1;
   ntriangulos=1;

   // In the first round, ntriangulos = 1
   // We have to create 3 triangles out of them.
   // In the second round, ntriangulos = 3
   // We have to create 9 triangles out of them.
   // In the third round, ntriangulos = 9
   // We have to create 27 triangles out of them.

   // We need to stop the iteration when ntriangulos*3 > NTRIANGULOS

   while(3*ntriangulos <= NTRIANGULOS)
   {
      // The loop can also be:
      // for( n = 0 n < ntriangulos; n++)
      for(n=ntriangulos-1; n >= 0 ; n--)
      {
         // When ntriangulos = 3
         // The additional triangles need to be
         // added to locations with index 3,4,5, and 6.
         // When n = 0, we need to have m = 3, p = 4.
         // When n = 1, we need to have m = 5, p = 6.

         m=ntriangulos+n*2;
         p=ntriangulos+n*2+1;

         /* segundo triangulo */
         triangulo[m].xA=triangulo[n].xA + (triangulo[n].xB - triangulo[n].xA)/2 ;
         triangulo[m].yA=triangulo[n].yA;

         triangulo[m].xB=triangulo[n].xB;
         triangulo[m].yB=triangulo[n].yB;

         triangulo[m].xC=triangulo[n].xA + 3*(triangulo[n].xB - triangulo[n].xA)/4;
         triangulo[m].yC=triangulo[n].yA + (triangulo[n].yC- triangulo[n].yA)/2 ;

         /* tercer triangulo */
         triangulo[p].xA=triangulo[n].xA + (triangulo[n].xB - triangulo[n].xA)/4;
         triangulo[p].yA=triangulo[n].yA + (triangulo[n].yC - triangulo[n].yA)/2;

         triangulo[p].xB=triangulo[n].xA + 3*(triangulo[n].xB -triangulo[n].xA)/4;
         triangulo[p].yB=triangulo[n].yA + (triangulo[n].yC -triangulo[n].yB)/2;

         triangulo[p].xC= triangulo[n].xC;
         triangulo[p].yC= triangulo[n].yC;


         /* primer triangulo - inicial */

         triangulo[n].xC=triangulo[n].xA + (triangulo[n].xB - triangulo[n].xA)/4;
         triangulo[n].yC=triangulo[n].xA +(triangulo[n].yC - triangulo[n].yA)/2;

         triangulo[n].xB=triangulo[n].xA + (triangulo[n].xB - triangulo[n].xA)/2;
         triangulo[n].yB=triangulo[n].yB;

         triangulo[n].xA=triangulo[n].xA;
         triangulo[n].yA=triangulo[n].yA;
      }

      // After we have gone through dividing 
      // the triangles, the number of triangles have 
      // been tripled.
      ntriangulos *= 3;
   }

   for(n=0;n<ntriangulos;n++)
   {
      fprintf(fout,"(%g\t%g) (%g\t%g) (%g\t%g)\n",
              triangulo[n].xA, triangulo[n].yA, 
              triangulo[n].xB, triangulo[n].yB,
              triangulo[n].xC, triangulo[n].yC);
   }

   fclose(fout);
   return(0);
}
```

**Update 2**

There might be a logic error in your code to compute the triangles. Here's a version that I can understand.

```
      for(n=ntriangulos-1; n >= 0 ; n--)
      {
         // When ntriangulos = 3
         // The additional triangles need to be
         // added to locations with index 3,4,5, and 6.
         // When n = 0, we need to have m = 3, p = 4.
         // When n = 1, we need to have m = 5, p = 6.

         m=ntriangulos+n*2;
         p=ntriangulos+n*2+1;

         x1 = triangulo[n].xA;
         x2 = triangulo[n].xB;
         x3 = triangulo[n].xC;

         y1 = triangulo[n].yA;
         y2 = triangulo[n].yB;
         y3 = triangulo[n].yC;

         x12 = 0.5*(x1+x2);
         x23 = 0.5*(x2+x3);
         x31 = 0.5*(x3+x1);

         y12 = 0.5*(y1+y2);
         y23 = 0.5*(y2+y3);
         y31 = 0.5*(y3+y1);

         /* segundo triangulo */
         triangulo[m].xA = x12;
         triangulo[m].yA = y12;

         triangulo[m].xB = x2;
         triangulo[m].yB = y2;

         triangulo[m].xC = x23;
         triangulo[m].yC = y23;

         /* tercer triangulo */
         triangulo[p].xA = x31;
         triangulo[p].yA = y31;

         triangulo[p].xB = x23;
         triangulo[p].yB = y23;

         triangulo[p].xC = x3;
         triangulo[p].yC = y3;


         /* primer triangulo - inicial */

         // triangulo[n].xA and triangulo[n].yA remain unchanged.

         triangulo[n].xB = x12;
         triangulo[n].yB = y12;

         triangulo[n].xC = x31;
         triangulo[n].yC = y31;

      }
```

Comment: How would you suggest fixing the problem of the loop. I dont exactly see why it stops since ntriangulos grows by 1 in every loop which directly afects n. Ive just tried writing p=ntriangulos+1 and it doesnt work.

Comment: Wow! Amazing! it comes out almost perfect!!! Now I understand what you meant. But when I graph it, the center triangle isnt completely empty and there are a few  fly away points on the right side of the big triangle. why did this happen? could it be becuase of how the coordenates are written? Im being so picky because its supposed to be a fractal, which means that different augmentations of it are supposed to be identical to the whole thing.

Comment: @user3618313 I just added another update to my answer.